# How to create edge index for large dataset?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am new in exploring the PyTorch Geometric framework
I've been trying to implement GCNConv, where it needs at least x (tensor) and edge_index.
As far as I know, the edge_index is created manually in the documentation examples. However, if the dataset is large, creating manual edge_index will be burdensome.

Is there an automatic approach to create the edge_index for such large dataset? Thank you